# Android root commands not working in application

Tags: android, shell, command, root

I was experimenting with some shell commands on a rooted Nexus 7 tablet and I found that only the commands that seem like they wouldn't need root privilege are being executed.

For example, if I call:

```
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c mkdir /sdcard/test");
```

the directory is created. But if I call:

```
  Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c mkdir /system/test");
```

Nothing happens.

(I have tried all sorts of commands, and tried all sorts of different syntax in case something was off, but only commands that I wouldn't need root access for get executed)

When I try to execute this command, I get the popup from SuperUser and grant my application root privilege but is there something else that I am missing? I have looked all around and as far as I can tell this should work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must quote the argument to `mkdir`, otherwise `su` will assume that `/system/test` is a user name and fail to run.

   `Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c \"mkdir /path/to/test\"");`
2. Some areas of the filesystem, such as `/system`, are read only due to the way the filesystem is organized/mounted. Root access won't change that, your command will still fail.

To verify whether what you're trying to do is possible, install a terminal emulator on the device and run the command by hand first.

Comment: Ok thanks! What I am really trying to do is use the "mount" command to  mount a connected USB OTG device. Is this going to be impossible due to the filesystem? When I plug in the device, a file is created at /dev/bus/usb/001. Is there any way to call mount and mount it to the filesystem?

Comment: You can possibly mount it with something like `mount /dev/bus/usb/001 /mnt/foo`, but mind the quoting when you pass the command to `su`.